# submit not working when used from admin.php

Tags: php, html, forms, include

I have an admin.php page with an include called programs.php. This include lives one folder down in /includes/programs_form.php. programs_form.php uses an action called image_programs.php which also lives in the includes folder. The submit button in the form works when called directly from programs_form.php, but does not work when called from admin.php. I'm guessing it has to do with how I'm calling image_programs.php, but I'm not sure... Thanks

HTML:

```
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Add A Program</h3>

    <div  class="wrapperadmin">

        <p style="text-align:center">

            <table width="400" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">           
                <form id="comment_form" name="Image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image_programs.php" method="POST">

                    <tr>
                        <td width="100">Program Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="commentarea" name="program_name" type="text" id="program_name" placeholder="Program Name."></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="100">Program Description</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><textarea class="commentarea" name="program_description" type="text" id="program_description" rows="10" style=" overflow:hidden; height:auto" placeholder="Your Program Descrition Here."  ></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
         <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="File" name="Photo" size="2000000" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png" size="26"></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>
                        <INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" size="26">
                        </td>
                    </tr>      


                </form>

            </table>

        </p>

    </div>
```

PHP:

```
    <?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $hostname = "localhost:3306"; 
    $db_user = "root"; 
    $db_password = "admin"; 
    $database = "smlc"; 
    $db_table = "program";
    $db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
          mysqli_select_db($db, $database);

    $uploadDir=dirname(__FILE__)."/images/uploaded/programs/";

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    $program_name = $_POST['program_name'];
    $program_description = $_POST['program_description'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$filePath);
    if (!$result) {
    echo "Error uploading file";
    exit;
    }
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
    }

    $sql_program = "INSERT INTO program (program_name, program_description,filepath) 
    VALUES ('$program_name', '$program_description','$filePath')";



    $retval = mysqli_query($db, $sql_program);
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ');
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Update Successful!');</script>";



    }
    else
    {

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty in trying to piece everything together as to which filenames are called in relation to the code bodies. If it doesn't work from within another file, it's most likely because of the conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` but I could be wrong. You'd need to include your "include" structure.

Comment: Note that relying on magic quotes and / or using `addslashes` to prevent sql injection, is a very bad idea. Use a prepared statement or escape the values using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Include structure is: admin.php is in the root and includes ../includes/program_form.php (the action ../includes/image_programs.php is called in program_form.php)

Comment: absolutely right jeroen just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my  tags were sitting inside my  tags preventing it from reading the action correctly. I apparently need more coffee